# how to reload the current page when twitter bootstrap modal's cancel button clicked?

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, reload

Is it possible to reload/refresh the current page when clicking on the twitter bootstarp modal popup window?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using the standard Bootstrap modal markup, you could handle the modal 'hidden' event like this..

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  document.location.reload();
})
```

Demo: **http://www.bootply.com/62174**

Comment: Is there a way to add a listener to that markup so that the page would only refresh when a certain button was pressed. Not the close button?

Comment: I have the following Close button `button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Close`   How would i trigger a reload

Answer (score 3):

For BS3 it Should be something like

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
   document.location.reload();
});
```